# Prestashop 1.6 action hook debugging

Tags: debugging, module, hook, prestashop

I'm writing a Prestashop module that outputs data to an external webhook. I'm trying to find the params for the action hook I'm using (`actionPaymentConfirmation`), but I can't find any documentation on this hook and the only reference in the Prestashop code does not seem to be right.

I have tried both `var_dump` and `var_export` to get the data from `$params` into a file, but my file keeps turning up empty.

Is there any other way I can figure out what parameters this action hook has?

Answer (score 1):

That hook in v1.6 is only used in OrderHistory::changeIdOrderState by:

```
Hook::exec('actionPaymentConfirmation', array('id_order' => (int)$order->id), null, false, true, false, $order->id_shop);
```

So you have the id_order in the $params. The hook usually adds the cookie and cart in the exec:

```
if (!isset($hook_args['cookie']) || !$hook_args['cookie']) {
     $hook_args['cookie'] = $context->cookie;
}
if (!isset($hook_args['cart']) || !$hook_args['cart']) {
     $hook_args['cart'] = $context->cart;
}
```

But when in doubt, and if var_dump or similars doesn't work, i use the

```
file_put_contents("file.log", print_r($params, true) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

It saves to file the variable. The file is in the admin folder if the function using it is called in admin.